# Angular html doesn't pass the data to component

Tags: angular

I have a list, if one of the elements is clicked, it expands the sublist. However, I am not able to send data to the component.

```
<ul>
     <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
       {{selectedItem}}
       <li *ngFor="let photo of photos" 
     (click)="getsubfolders($event, 
      photo.albumName)">
              {{photo.albumName}}

              <ul *ngIf="photo.folder?.length > 0">

                  <div (click)="getNew(photo.foldernames)">{{photo.foldernames}}     

                  </div>   
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: photos }"></ng-container>
        </ul>
```

It's not able to pass the photo.foldernames on getNew function whereas it's printing the foldernames in div.
Can anyone help?

Comment: is the `getNew` method firing in the first place? Did you add a console.log() statement to test it?

Comment: I have passed the event and made it work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could answer your own question (and accept your answer)